# Computer turn on, but won't boot until I turn off power supply

Tags: boot, bios, power-supply, sleep, shutdown

It is a new build, when I turn on the computer, the CPU fans, case fans, LED, power button all turn on normally. However, there are no bio screen, monitor does not "wake up", the keyboard won't light up when I hit caps/num lock. Even the reset button won't work. Sometime after a few restart by holding the power button, it will boot to bios, and it will tell me that "boot failure detected".

Occasionally, when I turn on the PC, it will light up for a few seconds, then lose power, and turn back on again, and with the same problem as above.

After playing around with it a few times, I found out that if I turn off the power supply for a few seconds before turning on the computer, it will boot successfully every time. This problem also occur when my computer goes to hibernation or sleep mode.

Aside from this problem, once the PC is on, everything runs smoothly, I did a few stress test and benchmark, the performance match other similar PC, and the temperature are okay.

I tried re flashing the bio, updating all the firmware for my MB, nothing seems to fix it. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with some Intel boards and it turned out that with the RAM being "auto detected" (the right values) we had to manually lower the "CL" value (thus using "user defined" values). IIRC our CL values were 7 and we lowered them to 5. The machines booted perfectly every time after that little find.

Comment: I tried to set to a few different lower values, however that doesn't solve the problem. But thanks for the suggestion.